# f()+f() gives [3,3,3,3] and why not [3,3,3]

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def f(x=[ ]):
     x +=[3]
     return x

print(f()+f())
print(f())
```

**Output:**

**First:**

`[3,3,3,3]`

**Second:**

`[3,3,3]`

Answer (score 2):

because of a default parameter on python will be bound only once on program initiation. so for the first call of `f()` it returns `[3]` and change array that x refers to `[3]`.

so

```
print([3]+f())
print(f())
```

then the second call on `f()`, since `[]` has changed to `[3]`, the result will be `[3,3]` and also the array under a reference will be changed too.

so

```
print([3,3]+[3,3])
print(f())
```

similar to the next line. It will return `[3,3] + [3]`

```
print([3,3]+[3,3])
print([3,3,3])
```

That is how you get it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the output of `f()+f()` is `[3,3,3,3]` is because the *same* object `x` is added to itself.

Let's break it down:

After the first call to `f()` -> `x=[3]`.
After the second call to `f()` -> `x=[3,3]`

Now `f()+f()` = `x+x` = `[3,3] + [3,3]` = `[3,3,3,3]`

Maybe a way to demonstrate is to modify your function to print `id(x)`:

```
def f(x=[ ]):
    x +=[3]
    print(id(x))
    return x
print(f()+f())
#4370444584
#4370444584
#[3, 3, 3, 3]
```

If you wanted it to output `[3,3,3]`, you'd have to have the function return a copy of `x`:

```
def f(x=[ ]):
    x +=[3]
    return [val for val in x]


print(f()+f())
#[3,3,3]
```